# Slick Slider issue "onclick" don't work after breakpoint reached

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, slick.js

I have a slick slider with a "onclick" function. When i click on current slide i should add "active" class on image container. All work fine but on responsive, when resolution reach breakpoint, don't work.

Html code

```
<div class="my-gallery">
  <div class="my-gallery-image">
    <img src="">
  </div>
  <div class="my-gallery-image">
    <img src="">
  </div>
  <div class="my-gallery-image">
    <img src="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Slick Slider Code

```
$('.my-gallery').slick({
    slidesToShow: 4,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    dots: true,
    arrows: true
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 993,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2,
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 601,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1,
        }
      }     
    ]      
});
```

Script Code

```
$('.my-gallery-image').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

On breakpoint slick slider reload the slider and the js don't work.

How i can fix this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.
Need to set a breakpoint control

```
$('.my-gallery').on('breakpoint', function() {
    $('.my-gallery-image').on('click', function() {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the "active" class to your img tag, you should then use the jQuery `find()` or `children()` functions to get it.

It doesn't depends on the breakpoints you set.

Check out this example

```
$('.my-gallery-image').on('click', function() {
    $(this).children('img').addClass('active');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ob0L1rth/1/